# Networking Cable / Switch Near Air-Handling Unit

Tags: networking, ethernet, home-networking

I've done quite a bit of research (though none seems to come back with actual data) that when running network cables AC air-handling units should be avoided.

I had planned on running all my network cables into the top shelf of a cabinet (highlighted red in picture) where my switch, cable modem and router will be as well. Directly on the other side of this wall is my homes air-handling unit.

Would this distance here (around 8-12") be enough to avoid any interference? In either case, would shielded cables be of any advantage?

I really appreciate any insight/advice!

Side view of air-handling unit, wall, and cabinet:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure about the ethernet cables, but a wireless router may experience interference with the WiFi...

Comment: When in doubt go with shielded. http://www.l-com.com/why-use-shielded-cat-6-cable-vs-unshielded-cat-6-cable

Answer (score 0):

No way this will be a problem.

I work in an industrial building we have high voltages, motors, transformers and all kinds of electrical devices very close (and most plug in to ethernet).

The problem comes in when you run cables very close to power for a long distance, the ethernet cable can become an antenna. However this can is easily over come by moving to the other side of a stud, or moving away from the power after ten feet or so.